# Running hand detection model tensorflow-lite through Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When I run the model for determining hands **mediapipe** [hand_landmark.tflite](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/models) through Python, I encounter slow work in the process of determining hands! More precisely, it is
`interpreter.invoke()`
Frame rate drops sharply from 40 to 4!
How can I increase the frame rate to 20 or 25?

```py
    # ...

    # Called before the loop
    def start(self):
        self._interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path = path_to_model)

        self._interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        self._input_details = self._interpreter.get_input_details()
        self._output_details = self._interpreter.get_output_details()

    # ...

    # Called in a loop
    def generate(self, img):
        if img.size == 0:
            return False

        img_resize = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))

        img_resize_expanded = np.expand_dims(img_resize, axis = 0)
        image_np_expanded = (np.float32(img_resize_expanded) - 0) / 255

        self._interpreter.set_tensor(self._input_details[0]['index'], image_np_expanded)

        self._interpreter.invoke()  # Slow !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        output_data = self._interpreter.get_tensor(self._output_details[0]['index'])

        return output_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information would make this easier to respond to:

1) Are you running this on Desktop or a mobile phone? TFLite is optimized for mobile (e.g. has optimization for arm) and support to run quickly on desktops (e.g. x86) is still a work in progress

2) MediaPipe is likely using the GPU delegate API when running on Android. Take a look at the tensorflow.org/lite docs on running with the GPU. See what accelerators they take advantage of and find how to enable it in the above docs. If they actually run on the CPU and use quantization, that is something to look into.